# Can't override process() method in SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

I have a SwingWorker class as follows:

```
    class RemotePlayersWorker extends SwingWorker<String[][], Object> {
        PlayerCanvas parent;
        RemoteHandler remote;
        String[][] players;
        int maximumConnections;

        public RemotePlayersWorker(PlayerCanvas parentCanvas, RemoteHandler remoteHandle) {
            this.parent = parentCanvas;
            this.remote = remoteHandle;
        }

        @Override
        protected String[][] doInBackground() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("TEST 1");
            players = remote.getConnectedPlayers();
            publish(players);
            return players;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String[][]> chunks) {
            for (String[][] chunk : chunks) {
                 // no need for the c variable
                 System.out.println(chunk.toString());
              }
        }

        @Override 
        protected void done() {

        }
    }
```

However, I'm getting errors when overriding the process(List chunks) method. Eclipse tells me this:

```
The method process(List) of type PlayerHandler.RemotePlayersWorker must override or implement a supertype method
```

However, as far as I can tell, I am overriding the method correctly - I get the same error regardless of what I set the list type to.

Is there any other reason I wouldn't be able to override process()?

I'm using java version "1.7.0_10" - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)

Answer (score 6):

The SwingWorker class is defined as follows:

```
public class SwingWorker<T, V> {
    ...
    protected void process(List<V> chunks) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, since your subclass is declared as

```
class RemotePlayersWorker extends SwingWorker<String[][], Object> {
```

The process method should take a `List<Object>` as argument, and not a `List<String[][]>`

Answer (score 4):

You have incorrect parameter in your `process()` method it should be

```
protected void process(List<Object> chunks) {
   /// do your stuff
}
```

It takes 2nd. generic datatype of `SwingWorker` class. Please read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

### Explanation:

```
public class SwingWorker<T, V> {

    // methods

    protected void process(List<V> chunks) {
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Here you can see more purely that `process()` method takes **`V`** that is in your case `Object`.

So either change it to `List<Object>` or reverse your signature of SwingWorker class(but then you need to change return type of doInBackground() method).

Answer (score 3):

Your siganture for the process method is wrong.

The signature from SwingWorker : `protected  void process(List<V> chunks)`

> **V** - the type used for carrying out intermediate results by this
>   SwingWorker's publish and process methods

So it should be :

```
protected  void process(List<Object> chunks)
```